# Python look for a format that match specific format

Tags: python, format, match

I have a list of data in CSV file.

I am using loop to make them into fields... I need a code that look for a field in code that do not match this type of code "[A9]9AA9#9" Lets say "A" can be any letter and "9" can be any number. However [ ] and # symbol must be in the same location as in format.

```
def code():
    match= 0
    tree_file.readline() # skip first row
    for row in tree_file: 
        field=row.strip()
        field=field.split(",") # make Into fields
        code=(field[4])        
        if code != "[X9]9XX9#9":   #HERE SHOULD BE THE CODE
            match+=1
```

Please can you leave some comment in code so I can understand them because I can't understand how other solution that are available is relevant to my problem.

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Can the `9` be a digit or a number?

Comment: It can be anything as long it is whole number including 0. Not something like 5.7 and negative.

Comment: I have updated my answer to match a number instead of a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you need is:

```
r'\[[A-Za-z][0-9]+\][0-9]+[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+#[0-9]+'
```

So the code can be like

```
import re

if re.search(r'\[[A-Za-z][0-9]+\][0-9]+[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+#[0-9]+', code) is None:
    match += 1
```

**Explanation**

```
[A-Za-z] : matches any alphabet
[0-9]+ : matches one or more digits
[A-Za-z]{2} : matches two alphabets
```

**Output**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "[X9]9XX9#9"
>>> re.search(r'\[[A-Za-z][0-9]+\][0-9]+[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+#[0-9]+', s) is None
False
>>> s = "ABCD"
>>> re.search(r'\[[A-Za-z][0-9]+\][0-9]+[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+#[0-9]+', s) is None
True
>>> s = "[A123]456BB8#789"
>>> re.search(r'\[[A-Za-z][0-9]+\][0-9]+[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]+#[0-9]+', s) is None
False
>>>
```

Comment: It gives me an error that "NameError: global name 're' is not defined"

I wonder what does re means in (re.match)?

Comment: @Dragnets Updated answer... `re` is a module for "regular expression".

Comment: OK, I just did it. 

However I just realized there is a problem with this code, It does the job but it doesn't prevent from duplicate codes. I might be wrong but looking at the code you gave I am not sure if it prevent from duplicate. If so how could I check it. With 30K rows and also right now my code is in class and it doesn't store them it just check the current code if match... then throws them away and goes to the next one. Maybe use of Dictionary or some simpler answer will do it? If you didn't understood what I mean then the best I think I should create a new question for that one.

Comment: It doesn't prevent duplicate codes. You are checking if NOT the code, so why do you need to check for duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the following regular expression. This will accept lowercase and uppercase letters (`[a-zA-Z]`) and digits in their respective places (`\d`). We first compile the `pattern`, which is the regular expression we are trying to match (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for a much more detailed regex explanation). You then use `re.match` to attempt to 'match' the input string to the pattern. If the pattern matches, the `group()` method will return the matched group. If it doesn't, the `re.match()` will return `None` (which you can handle better than I did below :) ):

```
In [11]: import re

In [12]: pattern = re.compile(r'\[[a-zA-z]\d\]\d[a-zA-Z]{2}\d#\d')

In [13]: re.match(pattern, '[X9]9XX9#9').group()
Out[13]: '[X9]9XX9#9'

In [14]: re.match(pattern, '[Z7]3JK2#1').group()
Out[14]: '[Z7]3JK2#1'

In [15]: re.match(pattern, '[ZZ]3JK2#1').group()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-48efdbbda230> in <module>()
----> 1 re.match(pattern, '[ZZ]3JK2#1').group()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

One way to handle the non-matching case is to assign the result to a variable and then process based on whether it returns anything or not:

```
In [16]: match = re.match(pattern, '[ZZ]3JK2#1')

In [17]: if match:
   ...:     print match.group()
   ...:     

In [5]:
```

Comment: @ATOzTOa may have been first, but you gave explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`reg = re.compile(r'\[[A-Z][0-9]\][0-9][A-Z]{2}[0-9]#[0-9]')` works for me...

The `-` operator defines a range and the [] must be escaped, as by [definition](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), the `[]` operator matches a set of characters. You could also use Unicode character classes to do this if you need a locale-independent solution.